# Save xml file in Windows Store application

Tags: c#, xml, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I want to save xml file, but I get error messages. Regarding the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy.aspx)
 I should use a class in the Windows.Storage, but I don't know which class I should use and how to use it.

```
string filename;    
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filename);

...

doc.Save(filename);

Error: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.IO.Stream'   
Error: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Save(System.Xml.XmlWriter)' has some invalid arguments
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(filename);
using (Stream fileStream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
{
   doc.Save(fileStream);
}
```